# Password not working for VeraCrypt on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, passwords, updates, password-recovery, veracrypt

I have important data, including a crypto wallet, on this drive that I cannot access right now.

The password is correct. The problem is I can't login with it. The only thing I did different was my login sequence, I didn't input anything for awhile and then it went off. So like this: I turn on the laptop, don't input anything, it goes off. I turn it on again, try my password like normal, it doesn't work.

I didn't know it could do that on the login screen, so I turned it on and entered my password and PIM. It's not working. I pressed <kbd>F5</kbd> to make sure it's the right password and PIM. It is. I figured I could enter BIOS with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, Windows can't auto-repair my boot problems, and I can't rollback updates.

I didn't write the recovery key file stuff to a USB. Yes, I should have. I also didn't realize the seed in Bisq isn't the seed for all my wallets.

Comment: Is the problem that you have forgotten the password to log in to Windows? It's not very clear from your question. Please use the EDIT button to make your question more clear, particularly in where the problem is occurring, what the problem is, and what you did leading up to the problem occurring.

Comment: The password is correct. The problem is I can't login with it. The only thing I did different was my login sequence, i didn't input anything for awhile and then it went off. So like this: I turn on the laptop, don't input anything, it goes off. I turn it on again, try my password like normal, it doesn't work. Thanks for responding. I'm pulling out my hair right now.

Comment: As I noted previously, use the EDIT button to add this information to your question. Also, it is a very short list of very rare reasons why your computer would not accept the correct password. So if the computer is rejecting your password, you're not typing the correct one.

Comment: I've done that now, I'm researching what thpse rare reasons might be. I think the password is correct though.

Comment: @Lafftar Just want to say, I think we all know how stressful something like this can be. My advice to you on a very basic level? The more you stress yourself about the password being correct, the less your mind will bring it back to you. I genuinely recommend you somehow resting up and doing as much as possible to not stress over this… And yes, I know this is stressful but still… Do other things to rest your mind. And honestly in a day or so you might have it come back to you or a new solution will present itself.

Comment: Also, when you say, “…went off…” and “…goes off…” do you mean the computer itself stops and powers off? Or something else?